# update records in file2 with data found in file1

Tags: python, algorithm, file-io

There is a large file with fixed format,file1. Another CSV file, file2 has id's and values, using which, specific portions of a record with same id in file1 need to be updated. Here is my attempt. I really appreciate any help you can offer to make this work.

file2 comma separated

```
clr,code,type
Red,1001,1
Red,2001,2
Red,3001,3
blu,1002,1
blu,2002,2
blu,3002,3
```

file1 (fixed width format)

```
clrtyp1typ2typ3notes
red110121013101helloworld
blu110221023102helloworld2
```

the file1 need to be updated to the following

```
clrtyp1typ2typ3notes
red100120013001helloworld
blu100220023002helloworld2
```

please note that both the files are fairly large files(multiple GB each). I am python noob, please excuse any gross mistakes. I'd really appreciate any help you could offer.

```
import shutil
#read both input files
file1=open("file1.txt",'r').read()
file2='file2.txt'

#make a copy of the input file to make edits to it. 
file2Edit=file2+'.EDIT'
shutil.copy(file2, baseEdit)
baseEditFile = open(baseEdit,'w').read()

#go thru eachline, pick clr from file1 and look for it in file2, if found, form a string to be replaced and replace the original line. 
with open('file2.txt','w') as f:
    for line in f:
        base_clr = line[:3]
        findindex = file1.find(base_recid)
        if findindex != -1:
            for line2 in file1:
                #print(line)
                clr = line2.split(",")[0]
                code = line2.split(",")[1]
                type = line2.split(",")[2]
                if keytype = 1:
                    finalline=line[:15]+string.rjust(keyid, 15)+line[30:]
                    baseEditFile.write( replace(line,finalline)
                    baseEditFile.replace(line,finalline)
```

Comment: What's not working at the moment? Is it working but slow?

Comment: @SimonFraser The script is not complete. I am essentially stuck and couldn't move forward in the last piece.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I get you right, you need something like this:

```
# declare file names and necessary lists
file1 = "file1.txt"
file2 = "file2.txt"
file1_new = "file1.txt.EDIT"
clrs = {}

# read clrs to update
with open(file1, "r") as f:
    # skip header line
    f.next()
    for line in f:
        clrs[line[:3]] = []

# read the new codes
with open(file2, "r") as f:
    # skip header
    f.next()
    for line in f:
        current = line.strip().split(",")
        key = current[0].lower()
        if key in clrs:
            clrs[key].append(current[1])

# write the new lines (old codes replaced with the new ones) to new file
with open(file1, "r") as f_in:
    with open(file1_new, "w") as f_out:
        # writes header
        f_out.write(f_in.next())
        for line in f_in:
            line_new = list(line)
            key = line[:3]
            # checks if new codes were found for that key
            if key in clrs.keys():
                # replaces old keys by the new keys
                line_new[3:15] = "".join(clrs[key])
            f_out.write("".join(line_new))
```

This works *only* for the given example. If your file has another format in real use, you have to adjust the indices used.

This little script first opens your file1, iterates over it, and adds the clr as a key to a dictionary. The value for that key is an empty list.
Then it opens file2, and iterates over every clr here. If the clr is in the dictionary, it appends the code to the list. So after running this part, the dictionary contains key, value pairs, where the keys are the clr's and the values are lists containing the codes (in the order that was given by the file).

And in the last part of the script, every line of file1.txt is written to file1.txt.EDIT. Before writing, the old codes are replaced by the new ones.

The codes saved in file2.txt have to be in the same order as they are saved in file1.txt. If the order can be different, or the there is the possibility that there are more codes in file2.txt than you need to replace in file1.txt, you need to add a query to check for the correct codes. That's no big business, but this script will solve your problem for the files you gave us as an example.

If you have any questions or need more help, feel free to ask.

EDIT: Besides some syntactic mistakes and wrong method calls you made in your question's code, you shouldn't read in the whole data saved in a file at once, especially if you know the files can get very large. This consumes a lot of memory and may cause the program to run very slow. That's why iterating line by line is much better. The example I provided reads only one line of the file at once and writes it to the new file directly, instead of saving both old files and the new file in memory and writing it as the last step.

Comment: Just for a level of indentation's sake, you could use `with open(file1, "r") as f_in, open(file1_new, "w") as f_out:`

Comment: Absolutely right, I just thought this way it's better to understand what i meant for beginners.

Comment: Understood! I do wonder if the OP would be better with a hash of some kind, sqlite database perhaps. Probably out of scope of the question, though

Comment: Yeah there are definitely much better/faster/fancier ways to solve this. But this provides an easy solution that works, further optimizations may be built by the OP later on.

Comment: @TobiasTomski Thank you for providing the solution. I will test this against my files and let you know. I will modify the code to reflect the correct indices.

Comment: Definitely keep us up to date!

Comment: @SimonFraser  you are right about the better ways to solve this. Once I slept over it, I thought of a solution in Hive that would make it a little simpler.

Comment: Thank you Tobias!! I really appreciate your help. Your solution worked like a charm. I've accepted your answer.